# how to access a localhost app from a container in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a web app running outside of a container (`localhost:8090`).
How can I access it from within a container in a `docker-compose` network?

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) answer that help for `docker`.

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - host
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-beta.6
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK: "http://localhost:8090/verify"
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: you tried to follow the answer and...? does `graphql-engine` need to access outside of container?

Comment: I can't figure out how to set the networks to the compose with multiple services

Comment: does `graphql-engine` need to access outside of container?

Comment: Yes, to my machine, a service running on localhost

Answer (score 2):

Add `network_mode: "host"` to your `graphql-engine:` and remove port mapping:

```
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-beta.6
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_AUTH_HOOK: "http://localhost:8090/verify"
```

`graphql-engine` would listen on host port 8080 and would be able to connect to `localhost:8090`

To make sure it worked, verify `/etc/hosts` file from the docker host is inside `graphql-engine` contianer .

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode)